# Which programing framework should I use to create an application on iPhone/iPad that should dress up a Silhouette?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Which programing framework should I use to create an application for iPhone/iPad. The application will have the capability to dress up a silhouette with different kinds of dresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That question is does not have a clear answer. You could either simply use several layers / views which contain images of your "dresses" and overlay them in a certain view hierarchy or you start drawing the "dresses" inside your application using several frameworks like CoreGraphics or QuartzCore ... depends on how much effort you spend to create your app.

Comment: Can I directly use dress images (png files) on the silhouette or do I need to draw them?

Comment: You can just use PNG files and arrange them via Multitouch. Look at UIImageView scaling, rotating, zooming, pinching etc.